# Securing a database using web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint application that needs to integrate with very sensitive databases. The data required is from multiple databases; almost 40 different databases on different servers.

The suggested design was to have a web service to integrate with, which will then connect to the required database based on the required business logic. However the concern is, if someone somehow got access to the server hosting this web service, all the database connections will be there.

Another suggestion was to have a dedicated web service for each database. This way even if someone got access to this web service, only one database connection will be there.

The question is, is there any known design that can work for this situation to add more security to the database connections?

Comment: Maybe Web.config connection string encryption is what you need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depending on your specific requirements. an easy way of doing so is to use "Open Data Protocol" OData. and then secure it with windows directory login, or perhaps ASP.NET login.

take a look at http://www.odata.org/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx

Comment: I think OData won't add security in my case